# Click on field label, it highlights related text field using Ext js

Tags: jquery, extjs, extjs4.1

I am new to Ext js.I am using textfield inside a form.This textfield created has field label,  is displaying fine.but problem is if i clicked on this field label then it highlights that textfield. i dont want this. please help me in this problem, how do i resolve it????
(sry for poor english) .

Answer (score 0):

this is the default behavior of a [html label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label), you need to prevent this for example with jQuery:

```
$('label[for="fieldId"]').click(function(e) { 
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In the config of your textfield, you can specify a "fieldCls". [Click here to read the doc](http://docs.sencha.com/extjs/4.2.2/#!/api/Ext.form.field.Text-cfg-fieldCls)

```
        {
            itemId: 'txtItemId',
            xtype: 'textfield',
            fieldCls: 'x-text-field-sample', // The name you want
            name: 'name',
            fieldLabel: 'Name'
        }
```

You just have to redefine the css of your textfield into your css file like this :

```
.x-text-field-sample {
    background-image:none;
    border-color:#000000;
}
```